# How to merge and add inner array of numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6, array-merge

I am working with a multi-dimensional array.
the following is my array:

```
let arr = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]];
```

the length of the inner arrays will always be the same.

I want create a function to add all the arrays elements together with their respective elements and create a new array with the result.
so my desired output is

```
result =[3,6,9];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested for loop for that.

```js
let arr = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]];
let res = Array(arr[0].length).fill(0);
for(let i = 0;i<arr[0].length;i++){
  for(let j = 0;j<arr.length;j++){
    res[i] += arr[j][i]
  }
}
console.log(res)
```